# zip not producing correct results

Tags: ruby, string, hash, dictionary

I have a string of letters and a string of numbers:

```
directions = ur
wieghts = 63 3
```

I want to hash them. Then, I expect to get something like:

```
u is 63
r is 3
```

I did this:

```
d = Array.new
d.push(directions.split(""))
w = Array.new
w.push(wieghts.split(/\s/))
@h = Hash[d.zip w]
```

Later in the program, I call the class that contains this zip:

```
f = info[1].gethash
f.each {|key, value| puts " #{key} is #{value}"}
```

but I get:

```
["u", "r"] is ["63", "3"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your strings and numbers are not valid Ruby objects. Your `@h` is useless, it is not used. What is `info`? What is `gethash`? Explain all variables.

Answer (score 1):

Change as below

```
d = Array.new
d.push(*directions.split("")) # splat the inner array
w = Array.new
w.push(*weights.split(/\s/))  # splat the inner array
```

`directions.split("")` gives you an array, which you pushed to `d`, whereas you are supposed to pus the elements of the array created by `directions.split("")`. Thus to meet this need, you have to use the **splat operator(*)**, like I did above `*directions.split("")`. Same explanation goes with the need of use `*`, with `*weights.split(/\s/)`.

Read doc of [`push(obj, ... ) → ary`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-push)

> Append — Pushes the ***given object(s)*** on to the end of this array.

Example :

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> a = []
=> []
>> b = [1,2]
=> [1, 2]
>> a.push(b)
=> [[1, 2]] # see here when I didn't use splat operator.
>> a.clear
=> []
>> a.push(*b) # see here when I used splat operator.
=> [1, 2]
```

One suggestion, I think below is enough :

```
d = directions.split("") # d = Array.new is not needed
w = weights.split(/\s/)  # w = Array.new is not needed
@h = Hash[d.zip w]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your variables declared correctly:

```
directions = 'ur'
weights = '63 3'
```

Then you can do:

```
Hash[directions.chars.zip(weights.split)]
```